# Create a free select image map

Tags: html, css, graphics, photoshop, gimp

I would like to know if there is a way for me to create image map with free selection. I have so far only found rectangle, polygon and circle crop. I want to know if it is possible to pick around a selected area.

Comment: https://www.google.fr/search?q=image+map+generator ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's called `poly`, it works pretty much the same, you'll just have to define a list of coordinates.
For example:

```css
img { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100px; height: 100px; }
div { position: absolute; }
#div1 { left: 17px; top: 51px; width: 49px; height: 38px; background-color: #ccc; }
#div2 { left: 17px; top: 26px; width: 0; height: 0; border-left: 25px solid transparent; border-right: 25px solid transparent; border-bottom: 25px solid #ccc; }
```

```html
<map name="map">
  <area href="/" shape="poly" coords="17,51,42,26,66,51,66,89,17,89" />
</map>

<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<img src="#" usemap="#map" />
```

The uneven ones are for X coordinates and the even ones for Y coordinates.

Comment: This is what the Polygon area of e.g. GIMP's Image Map filter does. In order to match a free selection, its outline will have to be approximated by straight line segments of that polygon, up to the precision that is desired - if necessary, down to the pixel level.